# Problems during the installation of rtl-sdr drivers in linux

Tags: linux, cmake, driver, rtl-sdr

I'm running in some problems during the installation of some drivers for my rtl-sdr.
I'm following the website's instructions for the installation. Here are the steps that I supposedly have to make in order to install the drivers:

> These are the instructions for installing our RTL-SDR Blog drivers.
> Type them into the Linux terminal one by one.
>
> First, if you already have some other drivers installed, please purge them from your system using the following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt purge ^librtlsdr
> sudo rm -rvf /usr/lib/librtlsdr* /usr/include/rtl-sdr /usr/local/lib/librtlsdr* /usr/local/include/rtl-sdr* /usr/local/include/rtl_* /usr/local/bin/rtl_*
> ```
>
> Next you can install the RTL-SDR Blog drivers using the following.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev git cmake pkg-config
> git clone https://github.com/rtlsdrblog/rtl-sdr-blog
> cd rtl-sdr/
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake ../ -DINSTALL_UDEV_RULES=ON
> make
> sudo make install
> sudo cp ../rtl-sdr.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
> sudo ldconfig
> ```

The text is taken from https://www.rtl-sdr.com/rtl-sdr-quick-start-guide/

I'm stuck at this line: `cmake ../ -DINSTALL_UDEV_RULES=ON`

When I run this the terminal starts spouting things like this

```
cmake: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8′ not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70)
```

I think that what the terminal is doing is trying to fetch the libraries from the xilinx path (I have installed Xilinx and some drivers for another project), when it should be fetching it from the rld-sdr-blog folder that I copied. (This is a theory and I could be totally wrong).

How do I get CMake to actually look for the libraries in the correct folder?

Comment: post the actual error messages, not just "things like". often "blaABI_x.y.z" _warnings_ come from using precompiled libraries, and are just that, warnings. you often see this for instance when mixing binaries/libraries from various "rhel" flavors. the point is, that "error" message isn't helpful out of context. post your whole error stack, and edit your question to include info about your Linux distro, and your Xilinx SDK